# Linker error after change in target name

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I have an iOS project with Google AdMob SDK installed using cocoa pods. When I started the project, the name of the project is called MAPPER. Then I renamed the project to GLITTER in Xcode. Xcode changed the name in almost all places except for cocoa pods. I had to rename in manually as in

```
target 'Glitters' do

pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.0'

end

target 'GlittersTests' do

end
```

I have to manually rename it. Then POD INSTALL worked fine. But my compile is failing with linker error as below

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-Mapper
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Full log message

```
Ld /Users/BharathMBA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Glitters-fakjqrbepxlfnzcvhrerurokbtzs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Glitters.app/Glitters normal x86_64
    cd /Users/BharathMBA/iOS/Swift/Mapper
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/Users/BharathMBA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Glitters-fakjqrbepxlfnzcvhrerurokbtzs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/BharathMBA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Glitters-fakjqrbepxlfnzcvhrerurokbtzs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/BharathMBA/iOS/Swift/Mapper/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-7.0.0 -filelist /Users/BharathMBA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Glitters-fakjqrbepxlfnzcvhrerurokbtzs/Build/Intermediates/Glitters.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Glitters.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Glitters.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lPods-Glitters-Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreTelephony -framework EventKit -framework EventKitUI -framework GoogleMobileAds -framework MessageUI -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -weak_framework AdSupport -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -force_load -Xlinker /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/BharathMBA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Glitters-fakjqrbepxlfnzcvhrerurokbtzs/Build/Intermediates/Glitters.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Glitters.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Glitters.swiftmodule -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -lPods-Mapper -lPods-Glitters -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/BharathMBA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Glitters-fakjqrbepxlfnzcvhrerurokbtzs/Build/Intermediates/Glitters.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Glitters.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Glitters_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/BharathMBA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Glitters-fakjqrbepxlfnzcvhrerurokbtzs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Glitters.app/Glitters
```

In the log I could see -Pods-Mapper is called for linking in line

```
-Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/BharathMBA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Glitters-fakjqrbepxlfnzcvhrerurokbtzs/Build/Intermediates/Glitters.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Glitters.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Glitters.swiftmodule -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -lPods-Mapper -lPods-Glitters -Xlinker -dependency_info
```

I am not sure how to get rid of this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Updating your pods may clear this error. try once.

Comment: I tried updating cocoa pods and and tried pod update but then the issue exsists. I created a new project folder and moved all the files to the new project to get around this issue

Answer (score 9):

Go to the `General` tab of your target and scroll to section named `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`.

Here, you should see 2 references to your Pods' framework:

- one with the name `Pods_<previous-target-name>.framework`
- a second with the name `Pods_<current-target-name>.framework`

Delete the reference to pod `Pods_<previous-target-name>.framework`.

Comment: Thanks! That helped.

Comment: I had a similar problem, but in a unit test target that I renamed. The problem was the old and new name were both in the Link Binary with Libraries section of the Build Phases tab.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that some paths were not changed by xcode. I ended up doing the following:

1. Select your project file (top most entry in your xcode workspace)
2. Select the `target` you use to build your app
3. Switch to the `build phases` tab
4. Find the `[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks` and the `[CP] Copy Pods Frameworks` phase
5. Open them and you will see that they still have the old file path in there.
6. Change the file paths so they fit your new project name

However, this only gave me more errors. I selected the project itself this time and expanded the `Configurations` section. Here I saw that a lot of old references were used. Instead of manually changing them I decided that it was easier to deintegrate and install the pods again by using `pod deintegrate` and `pod install` which then solved the problem.

I guess the first steps are unnecessary when deintegrating but I think it's good to know that they exist.